# TypeError: Attempted to wrap undefined property as function

Tags: ecmascript-6, sinon, babeljs, es6-class

The example below is simplified. I have a getter method:

```
class MyClass {
  constructor() {}
  get myMethod() {
    return true;
  }
}
```

which is processed by babel. And I want to mock it like this:

```
var sinon = require('sinon');
var MyClass = require('./MyClass');
var cls = new MyClass();

var stub = sinon.stub(cls, 'myMethod');
stub.returns(function() {
  return false;
});
```

But I get the following error:
`TypeError: Attempted to wrap undefined property myMethod as function`

And this happens on both version 1 and 2 of sinon library.

Answer (score 5):

Its an issue with how you defined your method `myMethod`. When you use `get` to define a method, it actually is treated like a property and not a method. This means you can access `cls.myMethod` but `cls.myMethod()` will throw an error as it is not a function

**Problem**

```js
class MyClass {
  constructor() {}
  get myMethod() {
    return true;
  }
}

var cls = new MyClass();
console.log(cls.myMethod())
```

**Solution**
You have to update your class definition to treat `myMethod` as a function like below

```js
class MyClass {
  constructor() {}
  myMethod() {
    return true;
  }
}

var cls = new MyClass();
console.log(cls.myMethod())
```

With this change now your `sinon.stub` should work fine

Comment: I understand that getter is treated like a property. But I cannot change the class definition as it's used in many places. I need a solution that keeps the getters in place.

Comment: Stubbing getters and setters are not yet supported. See here: https://github.com/sinonjs/sinon/issues/781