# How can I stub an anonymous function in Sinon?

Tags: javascript, testing, sinon

The following:

```
const sinon = require('sinon')

const a = () => { return 1 }
sinon.stub(a)
```

throws `TypeError: Attempted to wrap undefined property undefined as function`.

`stub` works if there is an object, so I tried using `this`. In node.js REPL (v6.11):

```
> const a = () => { return 1 }
undefined
> this.a
[Function: a]
```

However, in my mocha spec, it fails:

```
const a = () => { return 1 }                                        

console.log(a)
// => [Function: a]

console.log(this.a)
// => undefined
```

What am I missing? How can I make this work?

BTW: I'm aware that I can `stub` a method of an object, like this: `const stub = sinon.stub(object, 'a')`, but that's not what I'm after here with this question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: Attempted to wrap undefined property as function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42271151/typeerror-attempted-to-wrap-undefined-property-as-function)

Comment: Not really a duplicate. This is not about setters/getters.

Comment: You can't make it work like this. For stubbing, Sinon _requires_ a "root object" because it needs to replace the function reference that you want to stub in that root object. The `this` in the REPL only works because of how the REPL is implemented.

Comment: @robertklep apparently you are right. write this as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @PawełGościcki the posted answer basically says the same :)

Comment: It's missing an important bit, but I'll update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't make it work like this. For stubbing, Sinon **requires** a "root object" because it needs to replace the function reference that you want to stub in that root object. The `this` in the `REPL` only works because of how the REPL is implemented. In latest node (v8), it no longer automatically binds functions to `this` like described.

[sinon.stub](http://sinonjs.org/releases/v2.3.8/stubs/) takes in an object and then you can stub the properties. So you should be able to do

```
const obj = {
  a: (() => return 1; })
};
```

and then be able to call

```
const stub = sinon.stub(obj, "a");
```

As you witnessed, you set `const a` to be a function in your example -- it needs to be an object and then `sinon` can stub a specific property in that object. I believe the reason for this is it then gives it something sinon can reference hence why `sinon` can also support things like `object.method.restore()`.

Another workaround is to bind to `this` on your own (although that's not recommended):

```
const a = () => { return 1 }
this.a = a;

sinon.stub(this, 'a').returns(2);
console.log(this.a());
// => 2
```

Comment: Yes, I'm aware that you can stub methods of an object. But I'd like to understand why I cannot do it without having the object in place as this used to work in earlier versions of Sinon.

Comment: @PawełGościcki `sinon.stub(fn)` also doesn't work in older versions of Sinon. Do you mean `sinon.spy(fn)`?

Comment: It used to work like this back in the day. Here's an archeology link: http://sinon.readthedocs.io/en/master/Stubs.html

Comment: @PawełGościcki that's Python, though :D

Comment: LOL. Indeed! Maybe my memory is failing me.

Comment: Thanks a lot for updating my answer @PawełGościcki !